# Cannot delete properly rows on UI-Grid on Chrome

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

you can refer to this plunker:
[my plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Q1KwSQ?p=info)

To reproduce this issue just click on the second row ('Project Manager - phase 10') and click on the 'click me' button. This one should delete the current row selected.

Try it on Firefox or IE and all should work fine. Then try it on Chrome (my version is the 65.0.3325.181) and the row you selected doesn't disappear.

So, since they closed the discussion I had opened on their Github page I would like to know if you are able to reproduce this issue (so it's not just my problem)and if you have a solution (maybe someone already encountered this and solved it in some ways). Actually I cannot use the UI-Grid on Chrome for that...

```
I don't get why I must put some code here after the plunker, since I have like 4 files in it :-)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems it happens just on my pc (an just for my profile). I'm not able to reproduce it on others Chrome versions. I haven't any idea on the reason of this issue but... I actually don't care if it shows up just for me. It would have been a bigger issue if it was for all clients that need to use my application.